# how to random map users into groups using PHP preserving the equality of groups counts

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have to add users into a database, but these users must be grouped by a random category. 
Let's say my real case, I have 300 users to add and map them randomly to 3 groups (PF, PA and PO).
My client want to map these 300 users randomly not consecutively.
More detailed:
Suppose that there are no users mapped in any group. The first user will randomly be mapped to PO group.

Now I should have:

```
PF - 0 
PA - 0  
PO - 1
```

The next user can be mapped in any of these 3 groups as long as every group may contain at most 2 users more than or less then the other two.

The final map can be

```
PF - 100
PA - 100
PO - 100
```

(ideal case)

or:

```
PF - 98
PA - 100
PO - 102
```

or:

```
PF - 101
PA - 101 
PO - 98
```

Now, let's say I have following array in PHP

```
$map = array(
'PF' => 64,
'PA' => 66,
'PO' => 65
);
```

Ideally, the next group should be a random between `PF` and `PO` 
How could I get this in PHP ?

I appreciate any suggestion! Thanks!

Comment: Just pick a random group and put a user there.

Comment: I need a script to find what random group must be chosen between PF and PO to preserve the equality of group counts. No one group may not contain more than 2 or less than 2 users than the others groups.

Comment: in php, get an array of users and shuffle it. Then assign them sequentially from the new random order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the users are already in the database, an easy way to do it would be this:

Imagine you have a table called `users_groups` with two columns: `user_id` and `group`, where `group` is a `CHAR(2)` column (to hold the values 'PA', 'PF', or 'PO'). Execute the following query:

```
UPDATE users_groups
SET group=CASE WHERE RAND()<1/3 THEN 'PA' WHERE RAND()<1/2 THEN 'PF' ELSE 'PO' END;
```

That's going to assign each user to one of the three groups, in approximately equal numbers.

If you need to, you can design another query that will adjust the relative numbers in the groups.

As an aside, I see questions on SO all the time where people say "I want it to be random, but I want exactly *x* of this one and *y* of that one" - if that's the case, then it's not random. You're constraining the distribution.

**Edit**: Ok, based on your comments, here's a solution:

Assuming you have an array of users:

```
$users = array( 1, 2, 3, ... );
```

I'm just including a user ID value here because I don't know what sort of values you have for your users.

Sort the `$users` array randomly:

```
usort($users, function($a, $b){ return rand()<rand() ? -1 : 1; });
```

Step through the users and apply the groups one after another:

```
$groups = array( 'PA', 'PF', 'PO' );
$i = 0;
array_walk($users, function($u) use(&$i, $groups){
    insert_into_database($u, $groups[$i++]);
    if($i==count($groups))
        $i=0;
});
```

`insert_into_database` is just shorthand for whatever method you're using to run the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` query.

Because the list of users has been sorted randomly, the group that a given user is assigned to will be random. And because the groups are assigned in order (first PA, then PF, then PO, then back to PA, etc.), the number of users in each group will be equal (or as equal as possible if the count of users is not evenly divisible by three).

Comment: I have a table like your example but it has no data yet. It should be populated by a script while adding new users into `users_table`

Answer (score 0):

> I have to add users into a database, but these users must be grouped by a random category.

Do you mean *arbitrary* or actually random? If you mean a random category, then you are expecting distribution and basically roll a dice to decide which category. If you mean arbitrary, then the answer is completely different.

> Ideally, the next group should be a random between PF and PO How could I get this in PHP ?

Following that logic through won't make a lot of sense. You're not doing much different than just sequentially assigning them to a category. You should simply trust the random number generator.

When you roll a die you have a 1/6 chance to get any of the numbers. The outcome of your next roll has nothing to do with the previous rolls.

```
$categoryIndex = rand(0, 2);
```

Comment: Yes I mean arbitrary but, somehow random. I mean, if the group order is `PF` , `PA` , `PO` and first of all I have 2 users in `PF` and 0 users in `PA` and `PO` , I don't want to map next user in `PA` just because is the next group with available "slots". I need a random between these 2 groups but I also need to find that these 2 groups are available. I think the first thing I'd do is to find out which of these groups are available and then pic a random. Here is my problem.. how to find out what groups are available for a random selection?